# how to iterate on the color in matplotlib in a multiple plot animation

Tags: loops, matplotlib, colors, matplotlib-animation

i am trying to plot an current-voltage acquisition from an instrument but for different temperatures. I need to keep the structure as presented but i would like to have for each temperature get the plot in 1 uniform color then for the next temperature the color is changed so i can identify different plot and read their legend (the temperature). right now i get the animation but i cannot iterate on temperatures and colors. thanks

```
import random
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd

class IV_SWEEP():
    def __init__(self):
        self.IV_sweep()

    def init_instrument(self):
        #######settings
        self.data_points = 10  # number of steps in the sweep
        self.max_current = 0.001
        self.min_current = -self.max_current
                            
    def measurement(self):
        # Allocate arrays to store the measurement results
        currents = np.linspace(self.min_current, self.max_current, num=self.data_points)
        voltages = np.zeros_like(currents)
        temp_list = [300, 310, 320]  # want to plot a curve for each of this temperature
        for i in range(self.data_points):
            voltages[i] = random.random() + currents[i]
            now = datetime.now()
            self.record_csv(now, currents[i], voltages[i])
            self.animate()
            self.plot() # i am calling the plot method separately but dont know how to iterate the label so the color and legend is changed per temp
            plt.pause(3)      
        self.plot_enable = True

    def IV_sweep(self):
        self.xdata = []   
        self.ydata = []  
        self.init_instrument()
        self.measurement()
           
    def animate(self):
        data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
        self.xdata = data["Voltage (V)"]
        self.ydata = data["Current (A)"]
              
    def plot(self):
        plt.gcf()
        temp_list = [300, 310, 320]
        labels = temp_list
        # for lab in labels:
        plt.scatter(self.xdata, self.ydata, label=temp_list)  # need to add a different lab for each temperature scan
        plt.xlabel('Voltage (V)')
        plt.ylabel('Current (mA)')
        # plt.title("IV sweep at {} K".format(temp_list[i]))
        plt.title("IV sweep at temperature xx")  # call the temperature so it s printed as legend
        # plt.legend(loc='best')
        plt.tight_layout()
        return

    def record_csv(filename,timestamp, currents, voltages):
        filename = "test.csv"
        with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            header = ["Timestamp", "Current (A)", "Voltage (V)", "Voltage stdv (V)"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
            if csvfile.tell() == 0:
                writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(
                {
                    "Timestamp": timestamp,
                    "Current (A)": currents,
                    "Voltage (V)": voltages,
                }
            )
        csvfile.close()

IV_SWEEP()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random 

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)     


def main(i):

    # Actual parameters
    # A0 = 10 
    A0 = 2
    K0 = [1, 3, 5] 
    C0 = 5     
    # Generate some data based on these
    tmin, tmax = 0, 0.5
    num = 20
    t = []
    y = []
    for K in K0:  #would like to scan on K and plot each curve with a different color
        t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, num)
        y = model_func(t, A0, K, C0)
        ax1.scatter(t,y, label = K) # would like to have as a legend each K
        ax1.legend(loc="upper left")

def model_func(t, A, K, C):   
        return A * np.exp(K * t) + C

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, main, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks i am gettting the 3 plots at once and keeps looping.